# Error 404 on Wordpress while trying to access settings

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I recently deleted the `.htaccess` file from the cPanel. Then Wordpress started showing the 404 Error when I tried to access anything, even the Wordpress settings. I uploaded the `.htaccess` file back on cPanel, but it's still showing the 404 error and I can't even access the settings.

Comment: Did you open wordpress home page?

Answer (score 0):

create .htaccess file in root folder , and paste following code

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

following link may be your problem solution.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-destroyed-my-site-default-htaccess